# BUILD FAILED JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, build

Voy comenzando con JavaFX, y me surgieron 2 errores de Build cuando le di **RUN** a mi proyecto, como dato quiero añadir que estoy usando Netbeans 21 y JDK 21, y que si despues de dar **RUN** al proyecto, le doy un **Run File** al archivo Main si me muestra la panatalla.
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\day\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\App_FX\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1251: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\day\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\App_FX\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1259: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript

Adjunto una salida de pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías poner el código para ver donde puede estar el error.